# What is the best way to represent show and hide in icons?

Tags: icon, symbols, interface-design, user-experience, interaction

I have a web page that has a list of columns of information.  All columns have names and then some of the columns have items in them.   I want to have an icon to represent

1. Hide all empty columns
2. Showing all columns

All of the icons i see for hide look like "delete" so i want to see if there are any representations of "hide" icons that don't look like delete.

And for "show" the only thing i see is an eye graphic which doesn't seem very intuitive to me.

Does anyone have any recommendations for good "hide" and "show" icons?

Answer (score 4):

I think the most common and intuitive way to represent show/hide is the simple square box with "+" or "-" in the middle. Of course, there are many other  ways too:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

according to my view fa-eye for show & fa-eye-slash for hide is best for something to show and hide.
[image]

available font icon at : http://fontawesome.io/icons/
you can also able to apply the color on icon.

but you want to show or hide sub-menu than use other icon like plus,minus,down-arrow,up-arrow